# jQuery hide / show more button

Tags: jquery, button

I'm working on more / less buttons for text in jQuery. When my jQuery script is loaded, I want to only display some of the of the text in a div. In this case, any text > 650 characters I want to hide initially. I'm having trouble figuring out how to hide text above that limit using jQuery. Also, I am trying to create a function that will display the rest of the text in the div upon a button being clicked. Then, when the same button is clicked, the text will display only what was originally shown.

I have a fiddle that I have been working on that may be on the right track, but I am not sure if that is the case.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Fiddle ------  https://jsfiddle.net/carbot3000/f20bbh7a/99/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 250; // How many characters are shown by default
var ellipsestext = "...";
var rvwbody = jQuery(".reviewbody").html();
var c = rvwbody.substr(0, showChar);
var h = rvwbody.substr(0, rvwbody.length);

jQuery('.reviewbody').each(function() {
  if (rvwbody.length > showChar) {
    jQuery(".btnRead").show();
    jQuery(".reviewbody").html(h);
}
});
jQuery(".btnRead").click(function() {
jQuery(".btnRead").html(jQuery('.btnRead').text() == 'Hide me' ? 'Show Me' : 'Hide me');
jQuery(".reviewbody").html(h);
jQuery(".tstars").toggleClass("color");
console.log(h);
});
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA Please use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 250; // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var rvwbody = jQuery(".reviewbody").html();
  var c = rvwbody.substr(0, showChar);
  var h = rvwbody;

  jQuery('.reviewbody').each(function() {
    if (rvwbody.length > showChar) {
      jQuery(".btnRead").show();
      jQuery(".reviewbody").html(c);
    }
  });
  jQuery(".btnRead").click(function() {
    jQuery(".btnRead").html(jQuery('.btnRead').text() == 'Hide me' ? 'Show Me' : 'Hide me');
    jQuery(".reviewbody").html(h);
    jQuery(".tstars").toggleClass("color");
    console.log(h);
  });
```

Comment: ... I am sorry for even asking the question. I just forgot to change the variable from h to c. Thanks for the help, I can't believe I missed that!